# Check the Sharepoint user exists in AD

Tags: sharepoint

If a user is removed from AD, the user still exists in sharepoint. Now i want to check if a user exists in AD, so is there any sharepoint object model can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should configure User profile Sync to get updated info into SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is in the domain user Group, it collects all users under that user group and loops the list to that try to find the current user. If a user is found, it returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`.

Check this article [Check Whether User Exists in Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Sharepoint__User.aspx) that include some security related issues to achieve the requirement.

```
// Get ad users in the groups. Since MOSS does
                    // not support nested groups
                    // this will always be a collection of AD users
                    // and groups
                    foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
                    {
                        // Check if this is a Group
                        if (!user.IsDomainGroup)
                        {
                            // Verify if the user name matches the user name in group
                            if (user.LoginName.ToUpper().Equals(upperCaseUserName))
                            {
                                // if a match is confirmed, return from the method.
                                // There is no need to continue
                                userIsInGroup = true;
                                return; 
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                        // If the AD entity is a User Group,
                        // then check for users in that group
                        if (IsUserInADGroup(web, user.LoginName, 
                            username, out reachedMax))
                        {
                            userIsInGroup = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
```

Hope this help..

Comment: The code snippet here is a small part and the wrong part of the original article linked to in the answer.